# Creating a Message Box that runs a Specified Program (vbs)

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, msgbox

Take the following script that I have:

```
x=msgbox ("Do you want to recycle the Premiere Pro Media Cache?" ,4, "Recycle Premiere Pro Media Cache")

If box =6 Then
CreateObject("wscript.shell").run "C:\Expedited\Scripts\PrMCRecycler1"
End If
```

My goal is to get this VBS file (which brings up a message box) to run the batch file (the same way it would run when double-clicking it) when the yes button is pressed.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong above.  When I click No, nothing needs to happen, so I didn't specify anything for it.

Basically, since it brings up a yes/no message box, I just need to make the yes button execute the specified batch file.  I could really use some assistance in figuring out what's wrong.  When I try the code listed above, nothing happens upon choosing yes (besides the dialogue box going away).

Comment: On the first line you use "x=", but on the second line you use "box".

Answer (score 1):

Try this example and change the path of your batch file.

```
Option Explicit
Dim ws,Question,PathProgram
Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
'change the path of your batch file
PathProgram = "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
Question = Msgbox("Do you want to recycle the Premiere Pro Media Cache?",VbYesNO + VbQuestion, "Recycle Premiere Pro Media Cache")
If Question = VbYes Then
     ws.run DblQuote(PathProgram)
End If
'***************************************
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'***************************************
```